# How do I locate the contact data for the Address Book on Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, mac

How do I locate the contact data for the Address Book in the hard drive on Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 1):

The data is stored in several places. It's best to just export the data to the desktop if you want it in one file.

The complicated answer is in `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook` as well as in various cache files if you have enabled LDAP/open directory integration or other sync options to get contacts into and out of your address book.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/`

If you hit `File` -> `Export...` -> `Address Book Archive` you can create a backup. The resulting `Addressbook - <date>.abbu` file (which is actually a folder) actually just contains the contents of the abovementioned location.